# How to prevent if-statement from being executed only once when its condition is first checked?

Tags: java, android, loops, time, conditional-statements

I have initialized an int variable `i = 0`. My code has an infinite while loop which is checked immediately when the activity starts. In this loop I need to perform certain tasks after some time interval (e.g. 3 seconds). My code is similar to this:

```
while(1){
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - learningTime > 3000) {
            learningTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            i++;
        }
}
```

Since `System.currentTimeMillis() - learningTime > 3000` is true at the beginning of my program execution, `i` will increment quickly to `1` and later increments will be made every 3 seconds.

How to force `i` to increment from `0` to `1` in 3 seconds after the activity starts?

Comment: You should use a Handler for this sort of thing so as not to block the main thread.

Comment: Using an infinite loop to pause processing is not a good idea. On the UI thread you'll make your app unresponsive. On a background thread, use thread.sleep instead. You can create a Handler in your UI thread and use the postDelayed method to make some code run in it after a specified amount of time has passed.

Comment: @W.K.S Good idea. It would be nice to show me how I can implement a handler to perform this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign to learningTime the System.currentTimeMillis() value so it's 0 > 3000

```
learningTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

And, anyway you will block the main thread with this code.

That can be an example of Handler

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

[`Handler class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
[`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html)
[`Handler postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Anyway, you don't need anymore `learningTime` and `i` (?)

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. What I did is that I initialized a boolean flag to false and after `handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);`, the flag is set. I added my code which is after `while(1)` and executed it if the flag is set, hence, i is incremented at the beginning after the sleep function and later increments are made in my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a handler to solve this problem so that you don't block the main thread. 
I'm not sure if this is the ideal implementation though:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 3000;//3 seconds
private Handler handler;


protected void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super(b);

    handler = new Handler();

    //post an action to execute after an INTERVAL has elapsed.
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            //do your stuff
            doYourStuff();

            //post the event again until a stopCondition is met.
            if(stopCondition==false){
                handler.postDelayed(this,INTERVAL);
            }

        }

    },INTERVAL);
}
```

Comment: Now suppose that instead of the while loop, the onDraw() method is used which is called constantly by a loop thread. Would it be problematic to run this handler in the onDraw() method which is called every 10 frames per second?

Comment: That's a bit vague, may i ask what exactly you're trying to do. In principle, you can update the UI from a handler but I don't think you'd need a handler inside the onDraw() method.

Comment: Ok I'll try to make it clear. Suppose that what is inside of the while(1) loop in my question is put inside of the learnMode function in the code below,
`protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, null);
learnMode(canvas);
}`

Would it be OK to use this handler?
I am trying to implement it in my code now...

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments, here is an example of how to use a Handler to delay running some code until a certain amount of time has passed. Define a handler as a variable in your Activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Since that handler was created on the UI thread, anything you post to it will also run on the same thread. You can schedule code to run immediately or with a delay. For example:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}, 3000);   //Code will be scheduled to run on the UI thread afer 3 seconds
```